# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'yii\widgets\ActiveForm' not found

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

When working with Yii 2.0 I keep up facing this problem:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'yii\widgets\ActiveForm' not found"

I have checked the the widgets and `ActiveForm` is present.
I tried also with `yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm` but the same error keep ocuring.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'ID_ENSEIGNANT') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'DATENAISSANCE') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'MATRICULE') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'NOM') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'PRENOM') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'DISCIPLINE') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'FONCTION') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'SEX') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'TEL') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'EMAIL') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'ADRESSE') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'STATUT') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you got this class autoloaded? Have you got the same problem with that class in other places or is it only in that view?

Comment: yeah I got it uploaded (use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;) I've got the same prob in all views

Comment: Sounds like you don't use Composer, is that correct?

Comment: wen using `namespace` along with the function call you should not forget the starting `\ `, either add `use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm` on top of your view or change `<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>` to `<?php $form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin()?>`

Comment: I did all of that but nothing. Anyway its sound like I didnt install composer correctly beacause I started over and its working now

Answer (score 0):

You need to used activeform before used in page.

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
```